# How to change the button icon with javascript and open a new text area in MJQ

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile-website

Hello guys I have a Mobile JQuery form like this

```
<header>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
<link href="http://wstation.inmomundo.com/static01/cssii/costarica/themes/inmomobile.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://wstation.inmomundo.com/static01/cssii/costarica/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</header>

<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" style= "color:#006699 !important">

<h4>Estoy interesado(a) En la propiedad, </h4>
<input  onclick="opendiv1()" class="" id="radio-choice-1" name="opcmessage" title="" type="radio" value="1" />
<label for="radio-choice-1">favor de enviarme más información</label>

<input  onclick="opendiv2()" class="" id="radio-choice-2" name="opcmessage" title="" type="radio" value="2" />   
<label for="radio-choice-2"> deseo visitarla</label>

<input  onclick="opendiv3()" class="" id="radio-choice-3" name="opcmessage" title="" type="radio" value="3"  />
<label for="radio-choice-3"> envieme fotos</label>

<input  onclick="opendiv4()" class="" id="radio-choice-4" name="opcmessage" title="" type="radio" value="4" />
<label for="radio-choice-4">envieme más fotos</label>

</fieldset >


<textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea" id="textarea"></textarea>

<a data-rel="back" href="#pageone" data-icon="delete" data-inline="true" data-role="button"  data-theme="c" title="Close">Cancelar</a>


<div style="float: right; margin-right: -10px;">
<input  class="me" data-theme="c" data-role="button" data-inline="true" type="submit" data-icon="search" id="im_send_message" name="im_send_message" value="Enviar"  />
</div>

 </form>
</div>



</div>
```

I have following things to do which I am not able to do .

1.When some one clicks on one of the option a textarea should open and the content of the text area should be same as the input tag.

2.The data-icon="search" of Enviar button should change to data-icon="check" I have tried following script which did not work

**Script**

```
$("#textarea").hide();

function opendiv1(){
$("#textarea").show();
$("#textarea").html( "Estoy interesado(a) en la propiedad, favor de enviarme más información" );
$('.men').attr('data-icon','arrow-u').button().trigger("refresh"); 
}

function opendiv2(){
$("#textarea").show();
$("#textarea").html( "Estoy interesado(a) en la propiedad, deseo visitarla" );
$('.men').attr('data-icon','arrow-u').button().trigger("refresh"); 
}
function opendiv3(){
$("#textarea").shw();
$("#textarea").html( "Estoy interesado(a) en la propiedad, envieme fotos" );
$('.men').attr('data-icon','arrow-u').button().trigger("refresh"); 
}
function opendiv4(){
$("#textarea").show();
 $("#textarea").html( "Estoy interesado(a) en la propiedad, envieme más fotos" );
$('.men').attr('data-icon','arrow-u').button().trigger("refresh"); 
}
```

I also have a JSFIddle of it kindly have a look

**Answer**

With help of answer given by @Omar I was able to finish this thing 
here is a fiddle

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/QbFW8/1/)

Comment: Yes but the icon doesn't change in the ENviar button also I wanted to know if it is possible to write on function which can do the work instead of writting so many function      http://jsfiddle.net/9TFVe/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile wraps all types of *input* in a div. That div holds all styles, hence, if you want to do any changes to an *input*, you need to apply them to that div.

To listen to changes on *radio* buttons, you need to use `change` event.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
    $("#textarea").hide();
    $("[name=opcmessage]").on("change", function () {
        var text = $(this).closest("div").find("label").text();
        $("#textarea").text(text).show();
        $(".me").closest("div").removeClass("ui-icon-search").addClass("ui-icon-check");
    });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/QbFW8/)**

Comment: Yes Omar I was trying to learn how to listen to radio buttons for a while . this is just perfect

Comment: But this code doesnot work in my real website when I put it there . Can you please explain me how .on('pagecreate',function()) works ??

Comment: Hi @Vikram you need to add pageID I forgot to mention it. `"pagecreate", "#pageid", function`

Comment: oh! okay thanx let me see if that works . But wanted to inform you that . I have been trying to implement tap,change,vclick etc events even the touchstart none of these has worked so far IDk maybe its a javascript error

Comment: @Vikram sure, let me know if you still have doubt.

Comment: No  it still have the same problem as I told you none of these events are working . But what I did in the end is I just used your concept and added in my older script which I proposed in the question         <br>                                                       .function opendiv2(){
$("#textarea").show().html( "Estoy interesado(a) en la propiedad,deseo visitarla" );
$(".me").closest("div").removeClass("ui-icon-search").addClass("ui-icon-check");
}

Comment: Previously I had tried something like this                                                               $('.ui-radio').bind('touchstart',function(e){
 
}); and also I tried using vclick but none of these function works

Comment: for your code I implemented like this  $(document).on("pagecreate","#InformationForm", function () {
    $("#textarea").hide();
    $("[name=opcmessage]").on("change", function () {
        var text = $(this).closest("div").find("label").text();
        $("#textarea").text(text).show();
        $(".me").closest("div").removeClass("ui-icon-search").addClass("ui-icon-check");
    });
}). But it doesnot work I mean .on function or .bind etc are not working I guess

Comment: @VikramAnandBhushan which jquery version are you using?

Comment: JQuery Mobile 1.4.2 and JQuery 1.11.0

Comment: @VikramAnandBhushan can you update your question with `<head>` contents?

Comment: Umm Like you want only the header related with Mobile JQuery or complete <head> content ? @Omar

Comment: @VikramAnandBhushan yes related to jq and JQM. Because the code should work unless you're using old versions or loading JQM before jq.

Comment: I have updated the header content related with the JQ and JQM . ALso I would like to tell you that the header is being created with help of separate theme.tpl.php file . I mean my website is generated using a model almost like a MVC

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52035/discussion-between-omar-and-vikram-anand-bhushan)